# Missing Inputs on AWS Amplify Signup Form

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am using apmplify studio to configure authentication for an amplify react app. I chose username for login and chose email, profile and name for signup as shown in the image below. [image]

But when I do `amplify pull` and run the application with `npm start`, the signup form looks like [image]

It does not contain email, name, and profile inputs but when I submit by providing username and password, it shows me errors (visible on the form). After `amplify pull`, I have added the following two pieces of code in my application

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
```

and at the end

```
export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I am developing this app by following the [Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/aws-amplify-studio-masterclass/) if that may help identify the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same problem. The `Authenticator` component (which is also the one used in `withAuthenticator`) is supposed to derive these automatically after doing `amplify pull`, but for some reason this doesn't work at the moment.

I assume there is some configuration issue behind this, probably something with the user pools/identity pools since these come up a lot around authentication and `Authenticator` issues.

As a workaround until the underlying issue is found you can work with the `Authenticator` component directly (wrap your `App` component with the `Authenticator` component instead of using `withAuthenticator`) and specify the `signUpAttributes` manually, as documented in [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/configuration#sign-up-attributes). In your case that would be `signUpAttributes={['email', 'name', 'profile']}`.

I hope this helps! If you find the underlying issue I'd love to know as well since I couldn't get it myself.